# Delphi and TApro - Sending character to modem with new version of delphi not working right

Tags: delphi, modem, serial-communication

I make a program in delphi 2007 that send and receive data throught a modem. I never had a problem with it. Now i had to make a new version of the program and use delphi XE2 but now, some data are not transmit correctly.

Here is part of the data that i send :

```
 Lecture : array [0..12] of string =
   (Chr($68)+Chr($23)+Chr($23)+Chr($68)+**Chr($80)+Chr($80)+**Chr($6C)+Chr($31)+Chr($31)+Chr($51)+Chr($00)+Chr($00)+Chr($1A)+Chr($32)+Chr($07)+Chr($00)+Chr($00)+Chr($00)+Chr($00)+Chr($00)+Chr($0C)+Chr($00)+Chr($04)+Chr($00)+Chr($01)+Chr($12)+Chr($08)+Chr($12)+Chr($48)+Chr($15)+Chr($00)+Chr($00)+Chr($00)+Chr($00)+Chr($00)+Chr($0A)+Chr($00)+Chr($00)+Chr($00)+Chr($16)+Chr($16)+Chr($E6)+Chr($EC),
```

I use  `ACP1.PutString(Lecture[0]+Lecture[1]+Lecture[2]+Lecture[3]+Lecture[4]);`
to send the data and when i check the log of Apro, most character seem ok except `chr($80)` and higher. The extended ascii dont seem to translate correctly.

When i check the log, the character $80 is replace by $3F.

I know it is most probably a conversion problem between `ansistring` and `unicode` but I am unable to resolve it.

Comment: I assume the encoding used for the hex values is ANSI. So you should at least declare Lecture as array of AnsiString. Otherwise the characters are treated as Unicode characters.

Comment: I try that but nothing has change, i still get $3F in the log file.

Comment: You can avoid strings at all and use TBytes for your data. Then use PutBlock for sending.

Comment: BTW, the compiler should emit some warnings for your code. You'd better not ignore them.

Comment: Have you tried  `...of AnsiString =  (AnsiChar($68)+...`?

Comment: The replacement character `$3F` is a question mark (`?`) and is often used to indicate a failed conversion from one encoding to another one. F.ex. ISO8859-1 doesn't define $80 as a valid character. I have no idea of the internals of APRO and what conversion might take place between the input to `PutString()` and output to the log. Anyway, you seem to have a binary communication, so don't use strings at all, instead, as already suggested, use `TBytes` and `PutBlock()`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I try to use the PutBlock without much success. Not all data seem to transfer. Now, i did change all String to AnsiString and Chr to AnsiChar and its working now.